# In jqgrid, after setting stringResult=true, my filters no longer work

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, filtering

i was previously using the basic filter where filters would show up in the URL querystring as

```
 [Field]=[Value]
```

To support more advanced filtering, i switched **stringResult=true**

```
$("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true })
```

which is great but i have many pages that i just realized are broken as i had previously sent out links like:

```
http://www.mysite.com/Applications?Team=MyTeam
```

what is nice about this is that the filter is persisted as part of the URL.  Is there anyway i can support this type of format but still use stringResult=true on top of this to support the more advance filter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url like `http://www.mysite.com/Applications?filter=...` is also a part of the URL. Why it's less good?

About the broken old links I see no way as to modify there (one should know where they are solved) or to continue your server components support of old style parameters additionally to the `stringResult: true` style.

One more way is to use URL redirection of old style URLs to the new one, but the implementation is very depend on the web server which you use and the technique which you use to write server components.

**UPDATED**: For example the URL send to the server by [the page](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchDataUrl.htm) is

"http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchDataUrl.json?filters=%7B%22groupOp%22%3A%22AND%22%2C%22rules%22%3A%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22Status%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22ne%22%2C%22data%22%3A%22Completed%22%7D%2C%7B%22field%22%3A%22Status%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22ne%22%2C%22data%22%3A%22On+Hold%22%7D%2C%7B%22field%22%3A%22Status%22%2C%22op%22%3A%22ne%22%2C%22data%22%3A%22Cancelled%22%7D%5D%7D&_search=false&nd=1300712766637&rows=10&page=1&sidx=Id&sord=asc"

if you decode this with respect unescape JavaScript function you will receive the following:

"http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchDataUrl.json?filters={\"groupOp\":\"AND\",\"rules\":[{\"field\":\"Status\",\"op\":\"ne\",\"data\":\"Completed\"},{\"field\":\"Status\",\"op\":\"ne\",\"data\":\"On+Hold\"},{\"field\":\"Status\",\"op\":\"ne\",\"data\":\"Cancelled\"}]}&_search=false&nd=1300712766637&rows=10&page=1&sidx=Id&sord=asc"

Comment: thanks for your idea . .i am going to investigate URL redirection . .

Comment: do you have an example of how the URL looks with stringResult=true.  Since filtering call is using ajax, i haven't actually looked at a persisted url with a filter

Comment: @ooo: I updated my answer with url examples. You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see urls and full raw contain of the HTTP requests send and received to/from the server.

Comment: thanks.  i am still going to look into URL rewriting to support the simpler URL syntax as for certain cases it seems easier to remember